# Mysql connection problem with php

Tags: server, 22.04, mysql, php

I'm trying to install a new lamp test system on ubuntu 22.04, but I'm having troubles with php 8 connecting to the mysql database.

It gives an connection denied error on all scripts I use. However the strange thing is that phpmyadmin works with the same login credentials.

The error I get:
Access to database is denied for `databasenameremoved`: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] (trying to connect via (null))

This happens for multiple (all) database users. I'm sure that the username and password are correct.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Thanks,
Stijn

Comment: What is the connection string that you’re using? Is the connection using SSL or standard PDO?

Comment: The error above is with freshrss, I do not know the string it uses. On my own scripts (that also don't work) I use mysqli_connect($databaseName.$host, $username, $password);